# Error: ActionController::Unknown Format (for format.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm completing a project. I have a search field that accepts a url. Upon submit, my code scrapes data from a website and saves it in a variable. I want to use that data to automatically fill in form fields for the user on that same page.

Here's what I currently have in the view:

```
<%= provide(:title, "New Deal") %>
<h3 class="create">Step 1: <span class="text">Enter the wholesale URL and click add button to create a new deal.</span></h3>
<%= form_tag new_deal_path, id: "search-form", method: :get do %>
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:search, "Enter the URL:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add Deal", name: nil, class: "scrape-trigger", remote: true %>
</p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my controller action:

```
def new
  if params[:search]
    @response = Deal.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end #currently, can't get this to work.
  end
@deal = Deal.new
@deal.orders.build
@user = User.new
end
```

And here is the form I want to fill:

```
<div class="manual-deal">
```

```
<%= f.label :url %><br>
<%= f.url_field :url %><br><br>

<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %><br><br>

<%= f.label :image %><br>
<%= f.file_field :image %><br><br>

<%= f.label :retail_price_cents %><br>
<%= f.text_field :retail_price_cents %><br><br>

<%= f.label :wholesale_price_cents %><br>
<%= f.text_field :wholesale_price_cents %><br><br>

<%= f.label :minimum_bids %><br>
<%= f.number_field :minimum_bids %><br><br>

<%= f.label :estimated_delivery %><br>
<%= f.date_field :estimated_delivery %><br><br>

<%= f.label :delivery_method %><br>
<%= f.select :delivery_method, ['USPS', 'UPS', 'FedEX', 'Shyp', 'Local Pickup'] %><br><br>

<%= f.label :description %><br>
<%= f.text_area :description %><br>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
        data-description="Charge"
        data-amount="<%=@deal.wholesale_price_cents%>">
</script>
<% end %>
```

Following the advice on another question, I created a new.js.erb file in the view where I want this to happen. I thought I could fill the fields from there using:

```
function ready() {
  $('.scrape-trigger').on("click", function() {
   $('#deal_url').val(params[:search]);
   $('#deal_title').val(title);
   $('#deal_image').val(image);
   $('#deal_wholesale_price_cents').val(price_range);
   $('#deal_description').val(description);
 });
};
$(document).on('ready page:load', ready)
```

Not quite sure about this last part. Can someone point me in the right direction? I've been stuck on this for hours and haven't found a decent solution. I've found some other resources on Ajax, but nothing that works with what I need with this scraped data.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `@response` has all the information you're going to need when filling out the form. (Also note that `@deal` and `@user` will not be available to `new.js.erb` because they are defined after you render that file.)

This `.js.erb` file is rendered exactly once, exactly when it is rendered. Because of that, you don't need to worry about any `$(document).on('ready page:load', ready)` nonsense. You don't want this code to run when the page has loaded, you want it to run when the file is rendered. Get rid of it!

You should be left with just the `.val()` lines. This is a fine way to go about setting the value of things, but this file has no idea what `params[:search]` or `title` is. The only variable you passed to this file is `@response`. Use it!

So you should end up with something like the following:

```
$('#deal_url').val(@reponse.url);
$('#deal_title').val(@reponse.title);
$('#deal_image').val(@reponse.image);
$('#deal_wholesale_price_cents').val(@reponse.price_range);
$('#deal_description').val(@reponse.description);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The info in val(title) and the such were actually method calls from the helper, but removing the document.ready stuff did the trick.

Comment: Done! Sorry, I didn't notice that option. I tried up-voting it, but because I don't have enough rep yet, it didn't let me, so I thought there wasn't anything else that could be done.  Thanks again!